# What is the best way in numpy to use a vector of positions as indexes in a an nd array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array of agents positions:

```
positions = np.array([[row_0, col_0],
                      [row_1, col_1],
                      [row_2, col_2]])
```

I have a 2d grid, `grid = np.zeros((N, N))`. Now, let's say I want to mark all the cells where the agents are with `True`. What I have been doing is this:

```
grid[positions[:, 0], positions[:, 1]] = True
```

However, this is wordy and not scalable. Let's say now the positions are in 3d space. Now we have to modify the code like so:

```
grid[positions[:, 0], positions[:, 1], positions[:, 2]] = True
```

There is another way to solve the scalability problem, which is to do this:

```
grid[tuple(positions.T)] = True
```

However, it a involves a function call. Additionally, let's say there is not one, but two grids, such as:

```
grid = np.zeros((2, N, N))
```

and I wanted to mark only the first grid with True, then the method above does not work unless I do:

```
grid[0, (*tuple(positions.T))] = True
```

which does not look readable, and I wonder if there is a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I have been looking into this, and it finally hit me that adding a comma `,` in the parenthesis will allow tuple unpacking without explicitly calling the tuple constructor, like so:

```
grid[(*positions.T,)] = True
```

For the case of modifying the grid at index n of many grids combined at axis 0, the command becomes:

```
grid[(n, *positions.T,)] = True
```

Comment: Performance wise there's little difference among these.  The basic point is that dimension gets an array, or a tuple of arrays for all dimensions.  If `pos = positions.T` then `grid[pos[0], pos[1], etc]` is as simple as it comes.  Creating an index tuple from an array or list is used in a number of `numpy` functions.

Comment: I don't think you should worry too much about "scalability".  Yes, `numpy` allows `ndim` up to 32, but usually an application will be using 2d or 3d or some such small `ndim` throughout.  Use what's clearest for the application, even it requires a bit more typing.